# How do I retrieve the App insights request ID programmatically within our c# code

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitor

Background:

We have a web API hosted on our Azure cloud service, which is integrated with App Insights. The current setup allows for automatic logging of client requests made to this web API in App Insights. While this automatic logging feature is beneficial, the logs generated don't provide the level of detail we require for our operations.

Issue:

The primary challenge is that these automatically generated logs lack certain custom values that are crucial for our analysis. Specifically, after a request is logged in App Insights, there's further processing that occurs within the web API. This subsequent processing is associated with a correlation ID (corr id). However, I'm currently unable to establish a link between the initial App Insights logs and the logs generated during the further processing in the API. This lack of correlation is hindering our ability to trace and analyze the entire flow of a request.

Requirement:

1. Is there a way to enhance the automatically generated logs in App Insights by adding custom values?
2. Given that each request has a unique request ID generated by App Insights, is it possible to retrieve this request ID programmatically within our code? This would allow us to log it during the subsequent processing phases, thereby enabling correlation between the initial and subsequent logs.

The ability to correlate these logs is critical for our operations and troubleshooting efforts. Any guidance or solutions you can provide to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I couldn't understand how these requests are automatically generated.

Comment: To correlate request you should not have to use custom properties. Instead, look at the operationId, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-tracing-telemetry-correlation#data-model-for-telemetry-correlation)

Answer (score 1):

using this [reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-application-insights-for-exception-logging-in-c-sharp/) I am able to add logging with Request ID.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
  
    services.AddControllers();  
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>  
    {  
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Logs_App_Insights", Version = "v1" });  
    });  
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();  
}
```

```cs
 [ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var iteration = 1;
        var requestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        var operation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("WeatherForecastOperation");
        operation.Telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = requestId;

        try
        {
            // Log custom properties
            var customProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "CustomProperty1", "Value1" },
                { "CustomProperty2", "Value2" }
            };

            _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("CustomEvent", customProperties);

            _logger.LogDebug($"Debug {iteration}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Information {iteration}");
            _logger.LogWarning($"Warning {iteration}");
            _logger.LogError($"Error {iteration}");
            _logger.LogCritical($"Critical {iteration}");

            // Simulate some processing
            // ...

            // Use the request ID for logging
            LogInformationWithRequestId(requestId, "Log message here.");

            return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = new Random().Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[new Random().Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray());
        }
        finally
        {
            _telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
        }
    }

    private void LogInformationWithRequestId(string requestId, string message)
    {
        // Log information with the request ID
        _logger.LogInformation("[Request ID: {RequestId}] {Message}", requestId, message);

        // Log to the console with the request ID
        Console.WriteLine($"[Request ID: {requestId}] {message}");
    }
}
```

For  code Refer this [git](https://github.com/JayKrishnareddy/Logs_App_Insights/tree/master) Thank @Jay Krishna Reddy.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]
**Custom Values:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Technically a correct answer. But if you take a close look at the question, the real question is how to correlate telemetry. You should not have to use custom properties for that.